# Is there any progress towards a SHA-1 distinct chosen prefix collision?

Tags: cryptanalysis, collision-resistance, sha-1

The currently known collision attacks on sha1 are relatively difficult to practically exploit because the two colliding files must have mostly the same content. This limits attacks to file formats where garbage can be easily hidden and where conditional logic based on the value of a small block of garbage can be used to switch that apparent content of the file.

A distinct chosen prefix collision would be far more dangerous. A small block of garbage would still be needed but it could be towards the end of a potentially large pair of files and the rest of the content could be totally different. There would be no need for both files to contain all of the content and use clever tricks to hide half of it. The two files could have totally different formats if desired.

For MD5 a distinct chosen prefix attack showed up fairly soon after the first simple collision attack and was successfully exploited against a certification authority.

Is there any progress towards a distinct chosen prefix collision attack on SHA-1?

Comment: In summary, you are asking to the researchers doing research on SHA1 collision what is the current state of their research. Unfortunately unless you contact them directly I don't think you will get an answer on that one.

Comment: There's a [recent paper](https://ia.cr/2019/459) on this matter.